# Let $T,S$ be linear transformations, $T:\mathbb R^4 \rightarrow \mathbb R^4$, such that $T^3+3T^2=4I, S=T^4+3T^3-4I$. Comment on S.

Tags: linear-algebra, linear-transformations

Let $T,S$ be linear transformations, $T:\mathbb R^4 \rightarrow \mathbb R^4$, such that $T^3+3T^2=4I, S=T^4+3T^3-4I$. Then S is:

1. one-one but not onto
2. onto but not one one
3. invertible
4. non-invertible

(One or more correct options)

My attempt: $S=T^4+3T^3-4I=T(T^3+3T^2)-4I=T(4I)-4I=4T-4I$

How do I go about proving or disproving my options?

My thoughts on options # 1. and 2.: I'm guessing $S$ is one-one if $Ker(S)=\theta$ is one way to go, but how do I obtain the kernel when I don't know what the transformation is? $Ker(S)=\theta$ if $T=I$, which does satisfy $T^3+3T^2=4I$. But so can other $T$s.

My thoughts on options # 3. and 4.: $S$ is invertible if $det(S)\neq0$, which is possible $det(T-I)\neq0$, i.e. $T\neq I$. How do I show that?

Please help!

Comment: Given that you know that $S$ _can_ be the zero matrix (if $T=I$, there are certainly several options that you can eliminate as correct possibilities.

Comment: @DietrichBurde it i $S=T^4+3T^3-4I$ in my question paper...

Comment: @StevenStadnicki nothing is said about whether $S$ can or cannot be the zero transformation, or if $T=I$ or not. That's why I am so confused...

Comment: Diya: the point is that (as you noted yourself) $T=I$ satisfies the constraint, and if $T=I$ then $S=0$. The question is 'if all you know is <these givens>, what can you deduce?'  You cannot possibly deduce that $S$ is invertible, or onto, or one-to-one, because there are a pair $T, S$ that satisfy the constraints for which those statements are false.

Comment: There are certainly other solutions for $T$ (and thus $S$), but just knowing that _one_ solution makes those conditions false is enough to eliminate them as possible answers.

Comment: So none of these answers are true then? @StevenStadnicki

Comment: Note that *any* linear transformation $S:\Bbb R^n \to \Bbb R^n$ is onto if and only if it is one to one.

Comment: @Omnomnomnom that eliminates 1 and 2 then, thanks!

Comment: Well, you haven't proven that 4. is incorrect - in fact, you should be able to prove that any such $S$ is non-invertible.  Also, and this is essential, $det(T-I)\neq 0$ is _not_ the same thing as $T\neq I$ - there are many non-null matrices with zero determinants.

Comment: @StevenStadnicki can you please explain, to eliminate option (d) again? Also if not one-one, not onto..can i say not invertible too? That is, negation to the statement that one-one, onto implies invertible holds?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have correctly deduced that $S = 4(T-I)$.

It follows that $S$ is invertible if and only if $1$ is not an eigenvalue of $T$.  From the question, we do not have enough information to deduce whether this is the case.

Note that the first two options will *never* hold for an endomorphism on a finite dimensional space.

Answer (score 1):

In case that there is a typo, and that $S=T^4+3T^3-4T$, we have a clear answer, i.e., $S=T(T^3+3T^2-4I)=T\cdot 0=0$. Then $1.,2.,3.$ are false, but $4.$ is correct. (Note that $I$ and $T$ can look very similar for certain fonts, or handwritten notes).

Answer (score 0):

It's easy to reach at S=4(T−I).now x=1 is solution for the equation x^3+x^2=4, so 1 is and eigen value there for |A-I|=0

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).