# What are the conditions for one-one and onto of a given liner transformation?

Tags: linear-algebra, inverse, linear-transformations

Let $T:\Bbb R^4\longrightarrow\Bbb R^4$ be a linear transformation satisfying $T^3+3T^2=4I$, where $I$ is the identity transformation. Then the linear transformations $S=T^4+3T^3-4I$ is
a). one-one but not onto.
b). onto but not one-one.
c). Invertible.
d). Non-invertible.

on solving i get $S=4T-4I$, but how does this suggest invertibilty?
Also, Logically thinking option $a,b$, and $d$ are interlinked. So if only one choice is correct then i could simply say that yes option $c$ is correct.
But can someone give the general aproach?

Comment: The answer cannot be a) or b) because injectivity and surjectivity are the same for linear maps between same dimension vector spaces.

Comment: [link] (http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1411730/let-t-s-be-linear-transformations-t-mathbb-r4-rightarrow-mathbb-r4-su) @StevenStadnicki can you please explain, to eliminate option (d) again? Also if not one-one, not onto..can i say not invertible too? That is, negation to the statement that one-one, onto implies invertible holds?