# Is the operator invertible?

Tags: linear-algebra

$T$ is an operator on $R^4$. And $T^3 + 3T^2 =4I$. Let $S= T^4 +3T^3 -4I$. Is $S$ invertible?

After a little calculation I found that $x(x+12)^2$ is an annihilating polynomial of $S$. Now the minimal polynomial divides the annihilating polynomial. Now if the minimal polynomial has zero root , then $0$ is an eigenvalue, thus $S$ isn't one-one, hence not invertible. But if $12$ is the only eigenvalue of $S$, then what? I can't go further.

Comment: See this answer https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1411730/let-t-s-be-linear-transformations-t-mathbb-r4-rightarrow-mathbb-r4-su?rq=1

Comment: Yes, it is a duplicate, but in the link I didn't get the answer I wanted. Can't we get anything from the fact that S has only one eigenvalue and S is an upper triangular matrix? And moreover I just don't know how to delete this question.